# Python: How to sort a list of string values based on date and time?

Tags: python, regex, datetime

My list looks like this

```
list1 = ['3__01-11-2020 12-15 asiudhais', '12__04-11-2020 01-10 dgsisdwrais', '3__01-09-1990 02-34 dfsdweis']
```

the format is `<random 1 or 2 digit>__<date> <time> <random characters>`

I want this to be sorted by the date and time given in the name but also retain the full name.
I want it to be sorted by date and then by time in ascending order.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle list1.sort()   but the issue is that it takes in ```3__01-07-2021...``` first than ```3__04-06-2021...``` which is a month old.

Comment: You can pass a key to tell sort how it should do the sorting. In these case you need to extract the date string your interested in and create a datetime object form it (many examples online how to do this). Once you have a date time object you can sort quite easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first extract the date part from the strings. Since, the date contains 0-padded numbers (e.g. `01` rather than `1`), it is always 16 digits. To deal with the unknown length of the first number, you could either use a regex pattern like `^\d{1,2}__([\d\-\s]{16})`, which matches a 1- or 2-digit number, then two underscores, then a 16-character date, capturing the date in capture group 1, or you could do something like:

```
i = line.index('_') + 2
print(line[i:i+16])
```

Either way, you now have the time string e.g. `01-11-2020 12-15`. You can now parse this to get a `datetime` object, using the `strptime` function. (See https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior for how to construct the appropriate format string.)

```
import datetime

format = '%d-%m-%Y %H-%M'
print(datetime.datetime.strptime('01-11-2020 12-15', format))
```

`datetime` objects can be compared, so sorting the list using these objects as keys will do what you wanted, using `sorted(list1, key=...)`.

Here is the entire code:

```
import re
import datetime

extract_time_pattern = re.compile(r'^\d{1,2}__([\d\-\s]{16})')


def extract_datetime(line:str):
    # i = line.index('_') + 2
    # time_string = line[i:i+16]
    time_string = extract_time_pattern.match(line).group(1)
    format = '%d-%m-%Y %H-%M'
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(time_string, format)


list1 = ['3__01-11-2020 12-15 asiudhais', '12__04-11-2020 01-10 dgsisdwrais', '3__01-09-1990 02-34 dfsdweis']

print(sorted(list1, key=extract_datetime))
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one.

***Import necessary packages***

```
import pandas as pd
```

***Prepare the test data***

```
test_list = ['3__01-11-2020 12-15 asiudhais', '12__04-11-2020 01-10 dgsisdwrais', '3__01-09-1990 02-34 dfsdweis']
```

***Define the function to extract date form the input string***

```
def extract_date(str):
    start = str.rindex('_') + 1
    end = str.rindex(' ')

    return str[start:end]
```

***Sort the list by date & time***

```
sorted_list = sorted(list1, key=lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(f'{extract_date(x)}', '%d-%m-%Y %H-%M'))
```

***Result***

```
'3__01-09-1990 02-34 dfsdweis', 
'3__01-11-2020 12-15 asiudhais', 
'12__04-11-2020 01-10 dgsisdwrais'
```

Hope this one helpful to you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this,I stick with standard library.

I chose regex to get date and time values, then parsing them to create relevant objects:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime
import time

list1 = ['3__01-11-2020 12-15 asiudhais', '12__04-11-2020 01-10 dgsisdwrais', '3__01-09-1990 02-34 dfsdweis']

c = re.compile(r'(?<=__)(.+?) (\d+-\d+)')

def sorter_fn(item):
    d, t = c.findall(item)[0]
    date_ = datetime.strptime(d, '%d-%m-%Y')
    time_ = time.strptime(t, '%H-%M')

    return date_, time_

list1.sort(key=sorter_fn)
print(list1)
```

output :

```
['3__01-09-1990 02-34 dfsdweis', '3__01-11-2020 12-15 asiudhais', '12__04-11-2020 01-10 dgsisdwrais']
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-sort-a-list-of-datetime-objects-in-python you can:

1. Call sorted(date_list) with date_list as a list of datetime.datetime objects to return a new list with the elements of date_list in increasing order.

```
yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
today = date.today()
tomorrow = date.today() + timedelta(days=1)

date_list =[today, tomorrow, yesterday]
print('Before sorting:')
print(date_list)
print()


sorted_list = sorted(date_list)
print('After sorting:')
print(sorted_list)
print()

print('Original list:')
print(date_list)
```

OUTPUT

```
Before sorting:
[datetime.date(2020, 3, 27), datetime.date(2020, 3, 28), datetime.date(2020, 3, 26)]

After sorting:
[datetime.date(2020, 3, 26), datetime.date(2020, 3, 27), datetime.date(2020, 3, 28)]

Original list:
[datetime.date(2020, 3, 27), datetime.date(2020, 3, 28), datetime.date(2020, 3, 26)]
```

2. Call list.sort() with list as a list of datetime.datetime objects to change the original list with the elements in increasing order.

```
yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
today = date.today()
tomorrow = date.today() + timedelta(days=1)

date_list =[today, tomorrow, yesterday]
print('Before sorting:')
print(date_list)
print()

date_list.sort()
print('After sorting:)
print(date_list)
```

OUTPUT

```
Before sorting:
[datetime.date(2020, 3, 27), datetime.date(2020, 3, 28), datetime.date(2020, 3, 26)]

After sorting:
[datetime.date(2020, 3, 26), datetime.date(2020, 3, 27), datetime.date(2020, 3, 28)]
```